# Python Search text file & replace

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I want to take a list of words from textfile1.txt and replace the word "example" on textfile2.txt to whatever the text is on line one, line two and so on.. How would I do this?

Text file textfile1.txt

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

Text file textfile2.txt

```
url/example
url/example
url/example
url/example
url/example
```

What I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput("textfile2.txt", inplace=True ) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace("example", "user1"), end='')
```

My goal:

```
url/user1
url/user2
url/user3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it. In general, when you want to traverse 2 or more iterables (lists, files, etc) in parallel, odds are you can use `zip`.

```
with open('textfile1.txt') as f1, open('textfile2.txt') as f2:
    for l, r in zip(f1, f2):
        print(r[:r.find('/')+1] + l)
```

Comment: Good. But perhaps use `izip` (or Python 3) so the entire contents of 2 files does not need to be read...

Comment: you meant `print(r[:r.find('/')+1] + l)`

Comment: Heh yes I did, @Moses Koledoye. dawg, the OP is using Python 3 but you have a point.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks bro but I've ran into another problem, whenever
I run it to replace "example" it just outputs user1 

instead of:

URL GOTO=https://www.URL.com/example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 2712

what am I missing here?

I changed the code to  print(r[:r.find('/example')+1] + l) btw

Answer (score 0):

I would open the first file and read each line into an array: `['user1', 'user2', ...]`

Then, as you read the 2nd file, keep track of your line number.  Index into the array based on the line number and use that string as your replacement string.

Or use the zip() answer, which is also fine.